# Cubic Spline Interpolation in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working in image processing in C++ using OpenCV. I've a problem that requires cubic interpolation of a set of data. Are there any library files that I can use for this in OpenCV?

Comment: @akappa omg. language dude. we don't use the c-word here.

Comment: @kb, I'm sorry, I'll be more polite next time.

Comment: right, here the c-word is not allowed. we take either all the c-language or nothing.

Comment: When I had this problem I created an SVG with the path in it, then loaded the SVG into inkscape and told inkscape to smooth it.

Comment: what kind of "set of data"? Is it regular grid? Or non-uniformly sampled data? cubic bspline interpolation on a regular grid is not that hard. There's a nice paper about that you'll find if you google for "image interpolation and resampling". It even includes C code at the end.

Comment: Simply reticulate the splines and you're set.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for:

http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/opencv_interpolation.html

Comment: given link is in python i think and is it working like curves in photoshop ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there are any classes in OpenCV that will do cubic interpolation.

Have you considered [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (Gnu Scientific Library)? It should be able to help you here.

Take a look at gsl_spline.h and gsl_bspline.h.